# obj-c inherited variables are null

Tags: ios, inheritance

I have a base class which has a custom init method and then uses the value passed in through the init method to then call custom init methods on it's subclasses. problem is When i try to access variables that have had values assigned to them in the base class through the subclass Via `super`, the values are null, it's like the base class is a completely different object. Is it because the base class has not yet returned from it's init method yet? or am i going about the wrong way with inheritance here? code to follow.

**Interface**

```
@interface WTFGameBoard : NSObject
{
    @protected
    UIView *_answerView;
    UIView *_keyboardView;
    NSMutableArray* _answerSeperatedByCharacter;

    WTFAnswerBoard *_answerBoard;
    WTFGameKeyboard *_gameKeyboard;

    OpenGameViewController *_weakGameViewRef;
    GameInfo *_gameinfo;
}

-(id) initWithGameVC:(OpenGameViewController*)gameVC;

@property (nonatomic,unsafe_unretained)OpenGameViewController *weakGameViewRef;
@property (nonatomic,strong)GameInfo *gameInfo;

@end
```

**Implementation**

```
@implementation WTFGameBoard
@synthesize weakGameViewRef = _weakGameViewRef;
@synthesize gameInfo = _gameinfo;

-(id) initWithGameVC:(OpenGameViewController*)gameVC
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        //[weakGameViewRef ]
        _answerView = [gameVC answerView];
        _keyboardView = [gameVC keyboardView];

        self.weakGameViewRef = gameVC;
        self.gameInfo = [[CurrentGamesInfo sharedCurrentGamesInfo]_selectedGame];

        _answerBoard = [[WTFAnswerBoard alloc] initWithAnswer:[gameVC answer] blankSpaceImageView:[gameVC answerBox]];
        _gameKeyboard = [[WTFGameKeyboard alloc] initWithButtons:[gameVC letterSelectButtons]];

    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

**Interface**

```
@interface WTFAnswerBoard : WTFGameBoard
{
    NSMutableArray *WTFAnswerSpaces;
    NSMutableArray *_answerBlankBlocks;
    NSMutableArray *_answerGiven;
    NSMutableArray *_answerBlankOriginalPosition;
    NSString *_answer;
}

-(id)initWithAnswer:(NSString*)answer blankSpaceImageView:(UIImageView*)answerBox;
```

**Implementation**

```
-(id)initWithAnswer:(NSString*)answer blankSpaceImageView:(UIImageView*)answerBox
{
    if ( self = [super init] )
    {
        _weakGameViewRef = [super weakGameViewRef];//WHY U NO NOT BE NULL?
        _gameinfo = [super gameInfo];//WHY U NO NOT BE NULL?

        _answerBlankBlocks = [_weakGameViewRef answerBlankBlocks];
        _answerGiven = [_weakGameViewRef answerGiven];
        _answerBlankOriginalPosition = [_weakGameViewRef answerBlankOriginalPosition];

        [self SetupBlankAnswerSpacesForAnswer:answer withTemplate:answerBox];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is the fact that you are not invoking your custom constructor in your derived class:

```
if ( self = [super init] )
```

You are calling the default one, which is not overridden, and that doesn't initialize the ivars that you are trying to access.

You should call your custom constructor:

```
if ( self = [super initWithGameVC:gameVC] )
```

Of course this means that you need to pass along the parameter, or override the default constructor by initializing what you want to initialize without the need of any parameter.

Another thing that I don't understant is why you are setting ivars of the derived class in your custom class:

```
_weakGameViewRef = [super weakGameViewRef];
```

This basically does nothing because the ivar is the same, if you set the one of your base class then you can directly access it.

EDIT

Since you have a strange dependency issue here a quick solution would be to have something like

```
WTFAnswerBoard initWithWTFGameBoard:(WTFGameBoard*)board {
  self.board = board;
}
```

so that you can access the board that instantiates the `WTFAnswerBoard` and keep inheritance but switching the usage to composition (by adding a property to `WTFAnswerBoard` so that your recursive initialization doesn't occur.

Comment: I was doing as you mentioned before, directly accessing them, but i was getting Null so i thought i had to explicitly call the base classes version to get it, no luck of course...

Comment: Also i see the logic in your answer, however the first suggestion will not work as it causes a recursion loop, so it mean i will have to override the base class method. and hence this means one cannot pass in a parameter to initialize subclasses this way?

Comment: Why would it cause recursion? You call the derived constructor that calls your base constructor and you are done.

Comment: Maybe i did not understand your suggestion, but i tried it, so referring to the code above in the subclass `WTFAnswerBoard` custom  init which now looks like `-(id)initWithAnswer:(NSString*)answer blankSpaceImageView:(UIImageView*)answerBox andViewController:(OpenGameViewController*)gameVC` method i use `if ( self = [super initWithGameVC:gameVC] )` this call takes me back to my base class init method, which we just came from which then again calls WTFAnswerBoard custom init method...etc etc. So i must have misread your suggestion?